# Neither crontab nor anacron is running, how to debug?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, arm

I'm running Arch ARM on a PogoPlug and want to execute a file every hour, the file when call directly runs fine (it is executable), for testing the file

```
/etc/cron.hourly/crontest
```

contains

```
#!/bin/bash
date >> /root/log
```

First I copied it to /etc/cron.daily but it wouldn't run, run-parts --test lists it as valid but nothing shows in the log file, then I created a crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /etc/cron.hourly/crontest
```

To run it every 5 minutes while monitoring the logfile, it doesn't fire.

This is /etc/cron.d/0hourly

```
# Run the hourly jobs
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
```

and

```
journalctl -u cronie
```

just returns

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 1969-12-31 17:00:03 MST, end at Tue 2014-01-28 10:14:12 MST. --
```

So even though the PogoPlug doesn't have a rtc it has the correct time via ntp. What else can I do to debug cron / get it to run?

I'm tempted to just write a bash script that loops and sleeps x amount of seconds, but I'd rather figure this one out :-)

Comment: You must have the *incrond* or some *cron* daemon running.  Basically, it is a process which monitors all the cron files and does something like the script you are tempted to write.  *Cron* has a cost and in some embedded systems, like the PogoPlug, it may not be running.  Try `ps -ef` (maybe just `ps` with BusyBox) and see if *cron* is running.

Comment: If need be, there's [a cleaner way of doing it without cron](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/cron_functionality).

Comment: ps didn't show any cron entries so I ran crond by hand, is that the correct way to launch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure `cronie` is started. You can do so with the following command:

```
systemctl start cronie
```

This command will enable cronie to start on boot:

```
systemctl enable cronie
```

Answer (score 1):

Try user ***crontab -e*** to configure your cron. It will check your syntax of cron and it will save cron based on user. So **/var/spool/cron/'user'** will be the path.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did use crontab -e and the /var/spool/cron/root file reads */5 * * * * /etc/cron.hourly/crontest

Comment: did you tried run cron at shell with -f  *cron -f* and see what happens?.. change the log dir to /tmp too, maybe you have some sort of security app like apparmor

Comment: cron -f
-bash: cron: command not found

Comment: no apparmor or the like, just plain arch arm (alarm)